# why ng-bind doesn't show values from rootScope set by ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to store a variable within `$rootScope`. When I have a structure like this it all works OK, the second div displays the value:

```
<html ng-app>
  ...
  <body>
    <button ng-click="$rootScope.pr = !$rootScope.pr"></button>
    <div ng-class="{some:$rootScope.pr}">{{$rootScope.pr}}</div>
  </body>
```

But when I have a structure like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="root-scope-value-1">{{$rootScope.mobileMenuCollapsed}}</div>
    <div class="content-wrapper" ng-controller="MainController">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <div class="root-scope-value-2">{{$rootScope.mobileMenuCollapsed}}</div>
                    <button ng-click="$rootScope.mobileMenuCollapsed = !$rootScope.mobileMenuCollapsed">
```

The div with class `root-scope-value-2` shows the value from `$rootScope.mobileMenuCollapsed`, but the div with class `root-scope-value-1` which is up the DOM doesn't. Why so?

Comment: Just remove `$rootScope` from the view. $scope is implicit there...

Comment: Yep, it's now working :). Thanks. Can you please eloborate on the suggestion? Maybe as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use `$rootScope` in the view, scope's are implicitly bound to the views (even in case of `controller As` syntax, the alias becomes a property on the `$scope` which has the value of the controller instance reference). All the scopes (`$scope.$new()`) except isolated scope(`$scope.$new(true)`) are inherited ultimately from rootscope so you will have the properties available on the rootScope automatically available on the scope.  So here your controller `MainController`'s scope is inherited from the rootScope.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ISXSWc?p=preview)**

As a better practice always place properties on an object on the rootscope (As in the plunker) just so when you make any changes to the properties (properties of an object on the rootScope) from the child scope, the changes gets reflected on the parent as well, because both of them point to the same reference.

Comment: So basically since `ng-controller` creates new scope this scope had `$rootScope` property created on it by angular, while for the `root-scope-value-1` the `rootScope` property was defined on `rootScope`, correct ?

Comment: @Maximus Yes the scope created for your controller in this case is prototypically inherited from rootscope. if you have a controller wrapping this controller then this will be prototypically inherited from the above one and both of them ultimately from the rootscope.. See this example http://plnkr.co/edit/TbRJQK?p=preview  Also there is a great answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Comment: Yeah, got that. Thanks!